# Difference between passing '1/2' and str(1/2) to decimal.Decimal in python

Tags: python, string, decimal

I am learning about decimal type in python when I came under this doubt

Passing **str(1/2)** to **decimal.Decimal()** returns **Decimal('0.5')**

```
>>>import decimal
>>>decimal.Decimal(str(1/2))
>>>Decimal('0.5')
```

But when I pass **'1/2' as argument** it returns error:

```
>>>import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('1/2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

Can anyone please explain the reason behind this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the result of `str(1/2)`?

Comment: yes, it returns a Decimal object with value of 0.5 as shown in the code snippet

Comment: No, just `str(1/2)`, without the `Decimal`.

Comment: oh, now I get it, thanks for that. It evaluates the expression before converting it resulting into '0.5'

Answer (score 2):

When you make `str(1/2)` is being evaluated to `str(0.5)` and then to `'0.5'`. On your second example, passing the string `'1/2'` returns an error because the evaluation of expressions is not supported on initializing an instance of the `Decimal` class.

Answer (score 0):

`str(1/2)` is evaluated to a float (`0.5`) during compilation, long before it is passed to the `Decimal()` constructor (which expects a float or a string representation of a float). I doesn't try to evaluate a string that is passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, when you pass `1/2` to `str()`, it gets calculated. So `str(1/2)` makes **absolutely no difference** from `str(0.5)`.

So the question turns to `decimal.Decimal('0.5')` and `decimal.Decimal('1/2')`. When initializing instances of Decimal, the expression is supposed to be convertible to `float`. Surely the string `1/2` is not the case: `float('1/2')` gives ValueError.